# Animated series from 2000-2010(?) where a boy's grandad has a magic movie theater

Tags: story-identification, animated-series

I'm looking for an animated series about this boy that goes on adventures using his grandfather's or father's magical film reel that could take him to various times in Greek mythology.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If you recall any other details about the story or characters, please [edit] this question to add them in. The more info you can provide, the better.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be *[Mad Hatter Chronicles](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Hatter_Chronicles)*?

> Matt Hatter is an ordinary child who discovers that the monsters of his family's horror movies are alive in another dimension called "the Multiverse", controlled by the nefarious Lord Tenoroc. This dimension can only be accessed through the Notting Hill Coronet, his family's movie theater. With his grandfather Alfred trapped inside the Multiverse, Matt, along with his new friends Roxie and Gomez, must capture the movie monsters, save Alfred, and restore peace to the Multiverse