# Cartoon in which the protagonist used a portal in a theater to travel to other worlds, where he captured monsters

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I remember that the protagonist used to go to a sort of theater where there was a kind of portal. He went to these different worlds where he captured monsters and then turned them into little disks which he put in his watch. Every time he captured a monster, the main villain got weaker.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, was it animated in 2D (hand-drawn) or 3D (computer-generated)? And can you describe what the protagonist looked like, or tell us anything about any other characters in the show?

Answer (score 5):

Is this ***[Matt Hatter Chronicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Hatter_Chronicles)*** (2011-2015)...?

> Matt Hatter is an ordinary child who discovers that the monsters of his family's horror movies are alive in another dimension called "the Multiverse", controlled by the nefarious Lord Tenoroc. This dimension can only be accessed through the Notting Hill Coronet, his family's movie theater. With his grandfather Alfred trapped inside the Multiverse, Matt, along with his new friends Roxie and Gomez, must capture the movie monsters, save Alfred, and restore peace to the Multiverse.

The main character, [Matt Hatter](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Matthew_Luke_Hatter), discovers that the screen in his grandfather, [Alfred](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Alfred_Hatter)'s, movie theatre, the [Coronet](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Coronet), is a portal to the '[Multiverse](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Multiverse),' another dimension made up of twelve realms.

At the start of each episode, the main antagonist of the show, [Lord Tenoroc](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Lord_Tenoroc), releases a horror movie villain/monster from hexagonal discs called [Life Cells](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Life_Cell), to achieve some sinister objective or other within the Multiverse.

It used to be the job of Matt's grandfather to capture these villains/monsters, with the assistance of [Roxie](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Roxanna_Alexis) and [Gomez](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Alejandro_Diego_Gomez_Monteros), a pair of kids from the Multiverse, but Alfred has been trapped by Tenoroc, so now Matt has to take over.

When each villain/monster is critically harmed in some way, they "go hologram," at which point Matt can use a handheld device called a [Cell Blaster](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Matt_Hatter_Chronicles_Wiki:Usage_of_the_Cell_Blaster) to absorb and contain them, a bit like a [Ghostbuster's trap](https://ghostbusters.fandom.com/wiki/Trap).

He then plugs the Cell Blaster into the front cover of the [Chronicles](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Chronicles), a special book containing the Villain Vault, a prison pictured on a page within the book.

Shortly after Matt captures and imprisons a movie villain, the '[Black Knight](https://matt-hatter-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Knight),' near the end of the first episode, it's indicated that each time he does this, it makes Tenoroc weaker and his grandfather stronger.

You can view the scene in question at around the 18:56 mark in the video below:

Comment: And if so, this is a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/271637/animated-series-from-2000-2010-where-a-boys-grandad-has-a-magic-movie-theate/271638#271638